# Materialize - Full screen slider and navigation bar

Tags: slider, fullscreen, navbar, materialize

During a project's development I've decided to use a full screen image slider. As shown on the official site :  [Link](http://materializecss.com/fullscreen-slider-demo.html)

In this way the navigation bar is disappeared, but on a Youtube video I've seen that there is a way (which I don't know) in order to maintain both the full-screen slider and the navbar. Can anyone help me in this problem? Is there a way to take both of these features?
Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./src/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="./src/js.js"></script>
        <title>Home Automation - Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" lang="it">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/mycss.css">
    </head>

<body class="bkground">
    <nav class="teal darken-1">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo right">Domotic Home</a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">General</a></li>
                <li><a href="homecontrol1.html">Home Control - First floor</a></li>
                <li><a href="homecontrol2.html">Home Control - Second floor</a></li>
                <li><a href="privatearea.html">Private Area</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="slider fullscreen">
        <div class="main-content">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/1.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/5.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/3.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/6.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/7.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/9.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/11.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/12.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/13.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/14.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/15.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="./img/16.jpg">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here the css

```
.modal {
    max-height: 90%;
    max-width: 90%;
}
.bkground {
    background-image: url("/img/Sfondo3.jpg")
}
.sliderimg {
    border-color: black;
    border: solid 2px;
}
.floorimg {
    border-color: black;
    border: solid 4px;
}
.main-content {
    top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved this ? if yes please post answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer

> CSS

```
.slider-adjustment{
 position: fixed;
  top: 56px;  <!-- as nav bar has height of 56px -->
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
background-color:cyan ;

}
```

> HTML

```
 <div class="slider-adjustment">
     <!-- All html for slider goes here -->
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup. It can be done.I added a div.main-content after div.slider.fullscreen like below :

```html
div.main-content {
            top: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

and it worked for me. Just add whatever you want in that div.main-content element

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is not working in my case, if I add that class for the div , when I refresh the page the slider disappears.I posted my code too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing z-index

```
nav{
  z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything after the fullscreen slider in a div (say with id
content) and set CSS as follows :

```
#content {
position: relative;
top : 100vh;
}
```

credits: https://github.com/anshap1719